# How to create jumping wire using fritzing tool

Tags: arduino-uno

I am tying to design my circuit diagram with the help of http://fritzing.org/home/ I designed like below circuit where wires are simply straight.

[image]

I want some kinda jumping wires with this tool. Does anyone know how to create these jumping wires ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I was wondering the same thing after accidentally doing it (I didn't know I could).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Draw the wires
2. press and hold control button (mouse pointer will appear with a curve symbol)
3. drag the wire using mouse

[image]

[image]